# Ubuntu 20.04 won't boot and won't write any logs

Tags: lubuntu, 20.04

I've recently installed Lubuntu 20.04 on my Dell Latitude E6330 alonside windows 10. Everything went fine, I configured it to my taste (installed i3wm and some basic software) but after a couple of days, I tried to boot it and it won't do it. I've started it from the installation usb but I cannot see logs for today (I didn't use it for a few days)

The error I see is related to Support for core revisions 0x17 and 0x18 (I've invested a few days looking down that road but nothing useful came out of it). I reckon that is not a problem because I can use the WIFI adapter when I boot from the USB disk despite I also see that error.

I recall deactivating the WIFI chip in the BIOS and not seeing the error but it still hanged on boot.

Whatever the problem is, it happens AFTER that core revisions message, but I cannot see any logs in /var/log/

Did anyone see this issue before?

PS: I didn't use UEFI in the installation but I don't think that is a problem because I was able to use the laptop for a couple of days. Also I didn't install or reconfigure anything before being unable to boot.

Many thanks in advance, and please let me know if you need any extra info

PS2: I've just seen an error about sdb caching but my drive is mounted in sda (I reckon sdb is the USB drive)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *core revisions 0x17 and 0x18*, and you've tagged Lubuntu, but only mention Ubuntu in your description text which has me wondering why, and what is missing.

Comment: Support for cores revisions 0x17 and 0x18 disabled by module param allhwsupport=0. Try b43.allhwsupport=1 this is the message I meant. I tagged lubuntu because is the flavour I'm using, in case it helps...

Comment: I've managed to see remove the splash screen on boot and I can see several services failing: login, modem manager, hostname service... even grub, but that passed to quickly and the pause key didn't work

Comment: FYI: I'd forget trying to read messages on boot (yes they're too quick, the best you can hope for is a keyword such as *hostname* you mention).  You can read the messages via `dmesg` (as example) and then search for any keywords you recall... (search using `vi` commands in `less`)

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem!

It turns out that /etc/fstab had the wrong UUID for /. I might have misplaced the backups and restored another computer's one.

In case it is useful for anyone, I was able to hide the splash screen while booting pressing F1 and I saw a few errors there, seemingly not related to each other. It was the one about grub not being found which gave me the hint. Something was happening when mounting the file system.

I've checked /etc/fstab and I've noticed that the fs where / should be was not matching the result of running blkid | grep /dev/sda6 (where that fs is mounted from)

I've just booted from the installation USB, mounted /dev/sda6 in a temp dir, edited /etc/fstab and rebooted.